# Show Value Instead of text in select option

Tags: javascript, forms

I have country codes dropdown list, in select option text there countryname and ISD Code together, but I want only show ISD Code after Selection.

```
<select class="form-control-input" name="country_isd_code" id="country_isd_code">
  <option value="">Country Code</option>
  <option value="+244">Angola (+244)</option>
  <option value="+1">Anguilla (+1)</option>
</select>
```

I have searched for some other forums but I am not able to get how to do this. like if we select Anguilla, then it should show +1 there and if it is selected Angola, it should show +244

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle change event of select tag like this.

I updated code for display selected value as selected text.

```
$("#country_isd_code").change(function(){
  $("#codeselect").val($(this).val());
})
```

```js
$("#country_isd_code").change(function(){
  $("#codeselect").val($(this).val());
  //$("#country_isd_code option:selected").text($(this).val());
 
  $("#selecteditem").val($(this).val())
  $("#selecteditem").text($(this).val())
   $("#selecteditem").prop('selected', true);
   $("#selecteditem").show();
})
```

```css
#selecteditem{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control-input" name="country_isd_code" id="country_isd_code">
    <option id="selecteditem" value=""></option>
    <option value="">Country Code</option>                                                                                                                             
   <option value="+244">Angola (+244)</option>
    <option value="+1">Anguilla (+1)</option>
    </select>
   
   <input type="text" id="codeselect" />
```

Comment: not a bad idea it is, if i keep the Codeselect field as phone number. so one can write their phone number after that, what if i want this to be not editable in input field, he can write his number but cannot edit the country code, but if he change select box then it should change there..

Comment: you can set $("#country_isd_code option:selected").text($(this).val()); but after change, the value updated

Comment: do you want after select a value, selected text will be +244 ?

Comment: Yes i want select text should be +244.

Answer (score 3):

A solution with only a `<select>` element.

How it works:

- Initializes a hidden `<option>` that will be used for showing the selected option's value.
- When an option is selected:

  - affects to the hidden option's `value` attribute and text content the `value` attribute of the just selected option **if this value is not empty**. Then shows that hidden option.
  - empties `value` and text content of that option, then hides it, **if the chosen value is empty (`Country code` option here)**.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const select = document.querySelector('select');
  
  select.addEventListener('change', () => {
    const value = select.value,
      showValueOption = select.querySelector('.show-value');
    
    if (value === '') {
      showValueOption.style.display = 'none';
      showValueOption.value = '';
      
      return;
    }
    
    showValueOption.style.display = '';
    showValueOption.innerText = value;
    showValueOption.value = value;
    
    select.selectedIndex = 0;
  });
});
```

```html
<select class="form-control-input" name="country_isd_code" id="country_isd_code">
  <option class="show-value" value="" style="display:none;"></option>
  <option value="" selected>Country Code</option>
  <option value="+244">Angola (+244)</option>
  <option value="+1">Anguilla (+1)</option>
</select>
```